# How to clone an existing environment to the base environment in anaconda

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

I have some enviornments for anaconda (consider A, B, C). I would like to have the A environment as the base or root. How can I achieve this?

Most questions are about cloning one environment to another but I would like to clone an environment to the base.

I tried:

```
conda create --name base --clone tf2
```

But I got:

```
CondaValueError: The target prefix is the base prefix. Aborting.
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by changing the order. You can try:

```
conda create --clone tf2 -n base
```